# MYSQL Inner Join returning duplicate results ( Already Using DISTINCT )

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, distinct

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM group_members
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.group_id = group_members.group_id
WHERE group_members.user_id = *1* OR groups.created_by = *1*
```

However when it executes I get the following results:

```
Test - user 1
Test - user 2
```

But I want

```
Test - user 1, user 2
```

**I can't seem to understand how to modify my query to produce this. Would anyone have an idea?**

**In essence, I am trying to query for all the groups the user has either created or is part of**

Groups Schema:

- group_id (primary key)
- group_name
- group_description
- created_by
- group_creation_date

Group_Members Schema

- member_id (primary key)
- group_id (foreign key)
- user_id (foreign key - users table)
- date_added

Comment: You result does not contain record duplicates.. Yes it does contain a column duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Those rows are distinct/different - so DISTINCT is doing it's job; it ensures there are no duplicate rows - that means that if you select multiple columns it ensures there are no duplicate combinations. It does not ensure that there are no duplicate values for the field immediately following it as I think you are expecting.

I think you probably want to look at using GROUP BY with GROUP_CONCAT?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

I'm not clear which fields you are trying to select - but something like:

Try:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)
FROM FROM group_members
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.group_id = group_members.group_id
WHERE group_members.user_id = *1* OR groups.created_by = *1* 
GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: `SELECT *, ... GROUP BY GROUP_ID` is invalid SQL, Properly will cause invalid unrelated data to the grouped group_id

Comment: That still doesn't do what I'm looking for. **In essence, I am trying to query for all the groups the user has either created or is part of**